# asyncomplete.vim: how can I automatically show the completion menu after two succeeding 'word'-characters?

Tags: autocompletion

I'm trying to configure [asyncomplete.vim](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/asyncomplete.vim) so that the completion menu is shown when inserting at least two succeeding 'word'-characters.

However, I'm having trouble understanding why `asyncomplete#force_refresh()` or `asyncomplete#_force_refresh()` doesn't seem to work when used in a autocmd.

Here's a test config:

```js
set secure
set nobackup
set cot=menu,menuone
set noshowmode

" setup this test
function! s:setup() abort
  let s:testdir='/tmp/nvim'
  let s:plugdir=s:testdir.'/autoload'
  if !isdirectory(s:plugdir)
    call mkdir(s:plugdir, 'p', 0755)
  endif
  " requires plug.vim
  if empty(glob(s:plugdir.'/plug.vim')) && executable('curl')
    call system('curl -fLo '.shellescape(expand(s:plugdir))
          \.'/plug.vim --create-dirs'
          \.' https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/'
          \.'vim-plug/master/plug.vim')
    call assert_notequal(0, v:shell_error)
  endif
  let s:plugged=s:testdir.'/plugged'
  if !isdirectory(s:plugged)
    call mkdir(s:plugged, 'p', 0755)
  endif
  let &rtp=expand(s:testdir).','.expand(s:plugged).',$VIMRUNTIME'
endfunction

call <SID>setup()
call plug#begin(expand(s:plugged))
" Prabir Shrestha:
Plug 'prabirshrestha/asyncomplete.vim'
      \|Plug 'prabirshrestha/asyncomplete-buffer.vim'
      \|Plug 'prabirshrestha/asyncomplete-neosnippet.vim'
      \|Plug 'yami-beta/asyncomplete-omni.vim'
" Shougo Matsu:
Plug 'Shougo/neosnippet.vim'
      \| Plug 'Shougo/neosnippet-snippets'
call plug#end()

if !has_key(g:plugs, 'asyncomplete.vim')
  if exists(':PlugInstall')
    augroup Install
      au!
      au BufWinEnter * PlugInstall
         \| echomsg 'Please restart vim'
    augroup END
  endif
  finish
else
  augroup Install au! augroup END
endif

let g:asyncomplete_remove_duplicates=1
let g:asyncomplete_log_file = expand(s:testdir.'/asyncomplete.log')
let g:asyncomplete_auto_popup = 0

augroup Complete
  au!
  au FileType * if &omnifunc == ""
        \ | setl omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
        \ | endif
  au InsertCharPre * call <SID>check_minchar()
  au CompleteDone  * if pumvisible() == 0 | pclose | endif
augroup END

function! s:check_minchar() abort
  let l:char = getline('.')[col('.')-2].v:char
  if l:char =~# '\k\k'
    if !asyncomplete#menu_selected()
      " what to do?
      " call asyncomplete#_force_refresh()
      " call feedkeys("\<c-r>=asyncomplete#_force_refresh()\<CR>", "nt")
      " call feedkeys("\<c-o>:call asyncomplete#_force_refresh()\<CR>", "nt")
      " echo 'menu?'
    endif
    " I've also tried
    " if !pumvisible() | call asyncomplete#force_refresh() | endif
  endif
endfunction

call asyncomplete#register_source(asyncomplete#sources#buffer#get_source_options({
      \ 'name': 'buffer',
      \ 'whitelist': ['*'],
      \ 'blacklist': ['go'],
      \ 'completor': function('asyncomplete#sources#buffer#completor'),
      \ }))
call asyncomplete#register_source(asyncomplete#sources#omni#get_source_options({
      \ 'name': 'omni',
      \ 'whitelist': ['*'],
      \ 'blacklist': ['html'],
      \ 'completor': function('asyncomplete#sources#omni#completor')
      \  }))
call asyncomplete#register_source(asyncomplete#sources#neosnippet#get_source_options({
      \ 'name': 'neosnippet',
      \ 'whitelist': ['*'],
      \ 'completor': function('asyncomplete#sources#neosnippet#completor'),
      \ }))
```

---

<sup>I use neovim version 0.2.2 on linux 4.14.3-1-ARCH.</sup>